# GET DATA from XML and show on HTML - Input variable

Tags: javascript, html, xml, api

I'm trying to get data from a xml file and show inside inputs, but I need to get a parameter from a input.

This code is working when just click on the button, but it return the xml file with the parameter **'sbbr'**

this is my code:

```
<script>
  var icaocode = 'sbbr'
  var client;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    client = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  client.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/api/?icaoCode=' + icaocode, true);

  function buscarFunction() {

    var xmlDoc = client.responseXML;

    var heliponto = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("aisweb");
    for (i = 0; i < heliponto.length; i++) {
      data = heliponto[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      city = heliponto[i].getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      org = heliponto[i].getElementsByTagName("rmkText")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }

    document.getElementById('nome').value = data;
    document.getElementById('cidade').value = city;
    document.getElementById('org').value = org;
  }
  client.send();
</script>
<input id="icao"><button type="button" onclick="buscarFunction()">Buscar</button><Br>
<input id="nome"><br>
<input id="cidade"><br>
<input id="org">
```

I need to get this paramenter from here:

```
<input id="icao"><button type="button" onclick="buscarFunction()">Buscar</button>
```

but is not populating the variable **icaocode**, I have tryed this:

```
var icaocode = document.getElementById('icao').value;
client.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/api/?icaoCode=' + icaocode, true);
```

Comment: try logging the value of "-" + document.getElementById('icao').value +"-"; and see what it has, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'll probably have a solution, but I'd rather test it first, and you don't provide any means for that! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed, found a solution.
just needed to add the function `onload` and put all the code inside the main function like this:

```
<input id="icao"><button type="button" onclick="buscarFunction()">Buscar</button><Br>
<input id="nome"><br>
<input id="cidade"><br>
<input id="org">
<script>

  function buscarFunction() {
    var icaocode = document.getElementById('icao').value;
    var client;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      client = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    client.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/api/?icaoCode=' + icaocode, true);
    client.send();
    client.onload = function () {
      var xmlDoc = client.responseXML;

      var heliponto = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("aisweb");
      for (i = 0; i < heliponto.length; i++) {
        data = heliponto[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        city = heliponto[i].getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        org = heliponto[i].getElementsByTagName("rmkText")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      }

      document.getElementById('nome').value = data;
      document.getElementById('cidade').value = city;
      document.getElementById('org').value = org;
};

  }

</script>
```

and after that storage the variable from the input:

```
var icaocode = document.getElementById('icao').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `<script>` below the `<body>` tag after all elements have finished rendering. I think what's happening is that `document.getElementById('icao')` is returning null because there is no element with ID `icao` yet.